# Skip error if output contains a given string

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am working with ansible in linux and I am implementing a playbook that calls some roles.

`playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: my_hosts_group
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - start-app
    - run-app
    - stop-app
```

`start-app`

```yaml
- name: Start app
  command: sh startApp.sh
```

`run-app`

```yaml
- name: Run app
  command: sh runApp.sh
```

`stop-app`

```yaml
- name: Stop app
  command: sh stopApp.sh
```

What is happening is that if the app is already started, when I run the role `start-app` I get an error with the following output:

> "An instance of the server may already be running".

After this the execution of the playbook fails and it stops not executing the other 2 roles (`run-app` and `stop-app`).

I'd like to make some changes, in ansible side (not sh):

1. When this error happens (app is already started and when I got error with the mentioned output), I'd like to ignore this error and continue the playbook execution, and proceed to the other roles.
2. If `start-app` role doesn't fail, it should proceed as usual to next roles (normal behavior).
3. If `start-app` role fails, for any other reason, it should fail and playbook execution should stop (normal behavior).

What I did so far was changing a few things in the start-app role:

```yaml
- name: Start app
  ignore_errors: yes
  command: sh startApp.sh
  register: start_result
  failed_when: "'instance of the server may already be running' not in start_result.stdout"
```

But I am not sure if this is correct.

Now I got this output:

```
task: [start-app: Start App]
changed: [host1]
changed: [host2]
```

Can you help me in finding the better way to do this?

Comment: _Now I got this output:_ > this means the app was not started and it started it properly, what is your question here? The correct way yo do this is to make a [system unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) on top of your sh command then uses the [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) module to stop/start your application. But that's a too broad / not on topic question for StackOverflow, I would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, then I recommend going through the [ansible error handling page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)

Before we go further, it is important to check whether message you mentioned *"An instance of the server may already be running"* is registered in the `stdout` or in the `stderr`, both of these are attributes accessible in the `start_result` variable, the solution below assumes `stdout` but can be amended post your checks.

I would also look if `startApp.sh` uses any non-zero return code on failure, as it can be easier to write a condition based on `rc` code instead of parsing strings.

I would also check whether `command` is the right ansible module, and whether it should be [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) given you're actually running a shell script.

And finally, remove the `ignore_errors`, this blanks out all errors when you're actually trying to say error when server instance is already running.

```
- name: Start app
  command: sh startApp.sh
  register: start_result
  failed_when: "'instance of the server may already be running' not in start_result.stdout"
```

Comment: `remove the ignore_errors, this blanks out all errors` => to be accurate, it does not blank out the error (e.g. hides or consider success instead of failure). The error is reported by the task and written as a result in `ansible-playbook`'s output as well as in the task result if your register it. It just ignores it (as accurately described by the option name) and continues the playbook for any given host which are not yet considered as failed.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I used RC with failed_when which worked has I expected